# Ligntzone 4.2.0 install on ubuntustudio 20.04 LTS

Tags: software-installation, 20.04

I'm a new user of UbuntuStudio, 
I would like to use LigthZone 4.2.0 but it is not present in the repository. 
Is it possible to install the software on ubuntustudio 20.04?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The LightZone has its own [PPA on LaunchPad](https://launchpad.net/~lightzone-team/+archive/ubuntu/lightzone?field.series_filter=focal).

You can install the application version *4.2.0-0ppa1focal2* by running the following commands in the terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:lightzone-team/lightzone
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install lightzone
```